# SSH command gets hung

Tags: unix, ssh, freeze

I have SSH command within a while loop that executes on the remote system. And I see that more the number of times it executes, higher is the chance of it getting hung. Can anyone tell me if there is any SSH configuration or option available to prevent this.

```
 if [ -n "${services}" ]
 then
       while [ $flag -eq 1 ]
       do
          for list in $services
          do
            outcome=`ssh $user@$remoteserver "svcs $list" | tail -1 | awk '{print $1}'`
            if [ $outcome != "online" ]
            then
                 flag=1
                 break
            else
                 flag=0
            fi
          done
       done
else
       echo "Failed to get remoteserver list" 
fi
```

Comment: max startups? http://hypertable.com/documentation/misc/ssh_maxstartups/

Comment: Thanks for your response Robert. Attached the code. when a process is not online, code tries to ssh until it is online.. so it does ssh numerous times this way and that makes it hang.

Comment: Leo, thanks for your response. i tried maxstartups but dint help.

Comment: What is the value of `$services`?

Comment: Also, you can use `break 2` to exit the for loop and the while loop at the same time--no need for `flag`.

Comment: thanks chepner.. services is the list of processes.. eg: services= tomcat, application server.. etc

Comment: Perhaps you want `while [ $flag -ne 1 ]`? Also, is `flag` set to something before you enter that loop?

Comment: twalberg, i do not have problem with the flag. The main problem that I have is with SSH. This particular code segment above checks for the services to be online. It loops for every service until it is online. This means the SSH command runs in the loop and executes numerous times. This numerous execution is somehow making SSH get hung. I wanna know if there is any solution to prevent SSH from getting hung.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the ssh command reads from stdin, and this drains the input to your while loop.

Change the ssh command to an ssh -n command.  That is, add the "-n" option  to your ssh command.